# get values from dynamically generated inputs in knockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amitava82/dawkn/6/

The input elements will be generated dynamically based on json data received from server. Here I'm using text fields but it could be select, radio etc and *n* number of them. Now, I'm confused how do I get values from these input elements and also associate them with respective models item so that I can send them to server.  Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define custom model for **each** data. For example:

```
function DataModel(opts) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable();
    self.DisplayName = ko.observable();
    self.ValueDisplayType = ko.observable();
    self.Value = ko.observable();
    for (var i in opts)
        try{ self[i](opts[i]); } catch(e) {}
}
```

I've added the `for` so you can do this:

```
new DataModel({
    "Id": 12,
    "DisplayName": "Rad Accept Time Out",
    "ValueDisplayType": 0
});
```

Now when you create the `viewModel` you can do this:

```
var l = data1.length, parsed_data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++)
    parsed_data.push( new DataModel(data1[i]) );
self.models = ko.observableArray(parsed_data);
```

In your template you can use this:

```
<script id="displayTmpl" type="text/html">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.Value" />
</script>
```

and finally in `save` method:

```
self.save = function(){
    var newValues = ko.toJS(self.models);
    console.log(newValue);
}
```

function `ko.toJS` transforms `ko.observables` to its values. When you have `newValues` then you can stringify them with `JSON` for example and send them to the server.

That's more or less how I would do that. Feel free to ask additional questions in comments below.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot for the detailed solution! Works wonderful. I've added another for loop for auto mapping the DataModel properties.